# what's wrong with largest factor?

Tags: python

here is requirement:

```
def largest_factor(n):
    """Return the largest factor of n that is smaller than n.

    >>> largest_factor(15) # factors are 1, 3, 5
    5
    >>> largest_factor(80) # factors are 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 40
    40
    >>> largest_factor(13) # factor is 1 since 13 is prime
    1
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

here is my code:

```
def largest_factor(n):
  for m in n:
    if m <= n:
      if n%m == 0:
       return m
      else: 
       m = m+1
    else:
      return min
```

when I enter 15, output is 15

when I enter 20, output is 20.
why?

Comment: Since `min` is a built-in, how can it make sense to return it? Do you mean `m`? The code you actually show doesn't return anything but a runtime error since `for m in n` makes no sense when you input something like `15` for `n`. It can't possibly return `15`. Please show us your actual code.

Comment: Use a range: `for m in range(1, n):`

Comment: Update: I updated my response with the response to the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

## Response to current question

You updated your question while I was typing my code; so, here's an update.  You are missing proper `range()` syntax (refer to explanation bellow) and you need an list to store all relevante factors.  I added a `join` function to combine all elements in a list.

```
def factor(n):
    results = []
    for m in range(1,n):
        if n%m == 0:
            results.append(str(m))
    if len(results) == 1:
        return "factor is 1 since " + str(n) + " is prime"
    return "factors are " + ", ".join(results)

print(factor(15))
print(factor(80))
print(factor(13))
```

## Response to old question/titled question

Here's how to fix the code:

```
def largest_factor(n):
    for m in range(1,n)[::-1]:
        if n%m == 0:
            return m
```

### How it works

`for m in n` is not valid because the right side of the `in` operator requires an array (*or something similar*).  So, I replaced the second operator with `range(1,n)`.  `range` would produce a list like `[1,2,3,4,... n-1]`, then we can iterate through that.  However, we don't want it to count upward,  we want it to count downward, so I added `[::-1]`.  From there we are now iterating `m` backward through `1` to `n-1`. Yay.

Then we check if it is a factor and if it is, then we return `m`.

### Exception Checking - Primes

If the number is prime (meaning it has no factors), what do you want the program to return?  The code above returns 1.

But if you want it to return the number you inputted:

```
def largest_factor(n):
    for m in range(2,n)[::-1]:
        if n%m == 0:
            return m
    return n #or, if you want it to return false, change this line to return False
```